# How to save two different jpegs in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save to different scatter plots as two different jpegs.

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

```
ax[0].scatter(df_oz['o'], df_oz['t'], color='g', alpha=0.5, s=150)
ax[1].scatter(df_oz['o'], df_oz['r'], color='b', alpha=0.5, s=150)


fig.suptitle('T&R', fontsize = 20)
fig.set_size_inches(14,7)
fig.savefig('Hi and Lo.jpg')#this at least gets both graphs saved as one jpeg
```

Now I have tried:

```
fig.savefig[0]('Hi.jpg')
fig.savefig[1]('Lo.jpg')
```

But that doesn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The `figure.savefig()` is a function and can't indexing like what you do. If you want 2 different jpg files, you should separate it into 2 figures then save them separately. Try this:

```
# plot 1st figure and save
plt.scatter(df_oz['o'], df_oz['t'], color='g', alpha=0.5, s=150)
plt.savefig("Hi.jpg")

# clear the current plot
plt.clf()

# plot 2nd figure and save
plt.scatter(df_oz['o'], df_oz['r'], color='b', alpha=0.5, s=150)
plt.savefig("Lo.jpg")
```